# How to create a method dynamically with AspectJ? (Java)

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj

I want to create getters and setters for everything with an annotation because I use a text editor and it gets very annoying. Lol.

I don't see any way in the AspectJ documentation or reflections API.

I know I could do something in Bash or whatever, but this would speed up development and I could still use Geany or Emacs, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

AspectJ can only intercept methods - it cannot create them.

If you want to add getters/setters into the source code, a code generator/rewriter would be the best choice. Unfortunately these are not popular any more. Perhaps easier: Most popular Java IDE support generating setters/getters.

If you want to add getters/setters into the bytecode (.class file) a byte code library, like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried dynamic code but that's messy. I think most IDE's have some kind of scripting language you can use to write plug-ins -- I did that before in Notepad++ but yeah, Idea or Eclipse is the favoured way to go, for sure.